# Joomla forcing System URLS but SEF works

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

So we have a site running Joomla 3.6.5 and the problem we are having is that regardless of renaming htaccess.txt to .htaccess and activating SEF URL and the apache mod_rewrite features in Global config, we are still seeing system urls sitewide.

site can be seen here: http://www.pky.com

We migrated the site from a dev environment running 3.5.1 and we are not having this issue.  The issue only happened after upgrading to Joomla 3.6.4

Dev site can be viewed here: http://joomla.tko-orlando.com

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.  I've scoured the internet and all I can find are threads regarding the removal of index.php from the url, which is working fine.  I say this because when I disable SEF and mod_rewrite I get index.php in the url of the homepage and it's gone when those options are selected.

Am I looking at a route.php issue here?  Is there anyone else going through this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a web server different of Apache, you need to verify other options to than mod_rewrite. For IIS there is an instruction on [Joomla documentation page](https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs)

There are 2 reasons that may be causing this problem:

- The "System - SEF" plugin is disabled
- The Global Configuration settings are set not to have SEF URLs (check the `configuration.php` file, and make sure that you have the following values:

  ```
  public $sef = '1';
  public $sef_rewrite = '1';
  public $sef_suffix = '1';
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out a developer we had working for us wrote in a line of code which disabled SEF for the component for the sake of development.  In versions of Joomla! prior to 3.6.3, that line of code did not affect any other components or the joomla! default sef; however, with the 3.6.3 upgrade that was not the case.

We have since had a developer come in, rewrite the router, and now we are good to go.